# how do I get and display the referenced data in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have created two model users and post where users reference post.
This is my user model.

```
 var mongoose              = require("mongoose");
 mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/demo",{ useNewUrlParser: true });      
   
 var Post                  = require('./post');
 var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        username: String, 
        password: String,
        posts:[{
            type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: Post
     }] });
```

This is my post model

```
var postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title:String,
  content: String,
  likes:Number
});
```

When I create and save a new post to a specific user I get an id in the post field of the user model. like this:-

```
{
  posts: [
    60e33a2d18afb82f8000d8f0,
  ],
  _id: 60d9e931b5268920245c27f0,
  username: 'user1',
  password: '1234',
  __v: 5
}
```

How do I access and display the contents of the post field?

Thanks!

Comment: can you add payload request, and code that insert document.

Answer (score 2):

You can get and display Reference data in MongoDB with Aggregate.

Like:

```
await User.aggregate([
{
$match: { _id: ObjectId(user._id)}
},
{
$lookup: { from: "Posts", localField: "post", foreignField: "_id", as: "posts" }
},
{
$unwind: { path: "$users",  preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,}
}, {
$project: {
 " Now you can select here whatever data you want to show "
}
}
])
```

PS: If you have any confusion please do comment.

Thanks

Comment: I created a button in the ejs file which would in turn trigger this function :- app.post('/birthday/:id/gettingposts',function (req,res){
 
  User.aggregate([
  {
  $match: { _id: req.params.id}
  },
  {
  $lookup: { from: "Posts", localField: "post", foreignField: "_id", as: "posts" }
  },
  {
  $unwind: { path: "$users",  preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,}
  }, {
  $project: {
   content:1 // I want to display this on console... 
  }
  }
  ])
  
  res.redirect('/birthday');

  
})    but it is not returning anything. can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose has a powerful alternative to using `aggregate`. You can do this with [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) .

Use it like this  this will populate the ids inside the `posts` field with the actual post documents.

```js
User.findById(id).populate('posts')
```

```js
// Full example
try {
  const user = await User.findById(id).populate('posts').exec();
  for (let post of user.posts) {
    console.log(post.content);
  }
} catch (ex) {
  console.error(ex);
}
```

---

If I may, a small suggestion on how to setup your document model or just to show you an alternative. Don't reference the Posts inside your User Document. Do it the other way round and reference the User inside your Post Document.

```js
const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title : String,
  content : String,
  likes : Number,
  user : { type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
});
```

```js
// GET ALL POSTS FROM ONE USER

Post.find({user:id});
```

This way you don't need to use populate when trying to show all posts of 1 user.

Comment: I tried this -- User.findById(req.params.id).populate('posts').exec(function (err, user) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log('The blog contents are', user.posts);
     });                                                                                                    it showed me all the items in the posts array. I only want to console.log the content part of each post. How can I do that. Thanks!

Comment: Just iterate over it 
`for (post in user.posts) { console.log(post.content) }`

Comment: I am using this function in ejs template---<% user.posts.forEach(function(blogpost){%>
 <p><%=blogpost.content%> --- items</p>
<%})%>. There are no errors blogpost.comment is not displayed...

Comment: But the console log in the backend is fine ? Cause displaying the results on the client side or via an ejs template (ssr) is a completely different question. Please create a new topic with your problem.

Comment: Or you should update your question drastically and include the part where you try to render the result via an ejs template.

Comment: No the console.log in the backend is giving me undefined for all post items.

Comment: Sry I told you the wrong method for iterating over the array . You should use `for ... of` not `for ... in`. So `for (let post of user.posts) { ... }` should work. Also ... try using `ref: 'Post'` instead of `ref: Post` in your schema.

Comment: Thanks, it works I can console.log the post contents.